# Finder crashes - Maverick problems

Tags: finder, imac, crash

After upgrading to the Maverick version, I started having many issues that I never had before.

First of all, it is very common my iMac to open in a different user (even there is no other users available, kind of a safe mode I think), where I can basically do nothing, as it says I have no permission.

Secondly, my finder keeps crashing all the time, always when I try to preview a file, doesn't matter what kind.

Thirdly, my Mail just stops sending and receiving emails sometimes.

Fourthly, but not last, after the finder crashes, I can't open any program.

At last, my iMac late 2009 i7 8Gb is has never been as fast as it used to be.

I hope I had never upgraded to the new version of Mac OS.

Comment: You should probably reinstall the Mavericks.

Comment: Please run [Etrecheck](http://www.etresoft.com/etrecheck) and post a copy of the report to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com). Supply the pastebin link in reply.